# How can I send a query from a program to SqlServer and MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm developing a software. Where I have to send a query from the program (using a text-box) to SQL Server and MySQL. The user has to write it complete and then the program send it to those environments. I have already searched in every single site. But I can not find a help!

I just expect a help because I'm tired of searching and didn't find anything.

Comment: Is in ASP.NET, I forgot it

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I would suggest that you provide the code you have been using and show us where you are stuck so that we can chime in and help you. If you do not have code yet, I would suggest that you google 'write from asp .net to sql server' and 'write from asp .net to mysql'. Both searches should return several answers and tutorials. Pick a couple and see how far you can get. If you get stuck following the tutorials, post the code and we will be able to help. Note that there is no magical way of writing to both DBs at once, you have to write to one and then the other.

Answer (score 0):

Basil is completly correct with his answer but your question is a little vague, here's my interpretation of what you might need:

First I would suggest creating a Stored Procedure (SP) on the DB, there are many reasons why this is a good idea, but mainly it helps to seperate SQL from Client code. In that procedure you want it to be able to accept a Parameter (@TextBoxContent).

Then you will want your client code to look similar to this:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Server"] = @"Server_Name";
builder["User ID"] = "DB_Username";
builder["Password"] = "DB_Username_Password";
builder["Database"] = "DB_Name";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("My_Stored_Procedure", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextBoxContent", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = MyTextBox.Text; // Your textbox content

connection.Open(); // Connection must be opened
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close(); // You can't have multiple connections open
```